# bookmarklet for firefox bookmarks and act on pressing the bookmark button

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, bookmarklet

I have the folowing javascript code:

```
// `slice` to get an `Array` vs. `NodeList`, which may be "live"
var imgs = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('img.rg_i'), 0);

// clear out current contents
document.body.innerHTML = '';

// append each `<img>` back into the `<body>`
for (var i = 0, l = imgs.length; i < l; i++) {
    imgs[i].style.display = 'inline';

    document.body.appendChild(imgs[i]);
    document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(' '));
}
```

the above code remove everything from a page and shows only the pictures

Now in firefox i want to make a bookmarklet and bookmark in the bookmark toolbar.

I open any url in the firefox tab, after the page is opened, if i click this bookmarklet it should act on that page the javascript code above.

I have tried it but when i click its not doing anything, whereas when i open a firebug console and paste the code and run then it acts.

Answer (score 0):

I found it, on firefox bookmark toolbar, right click and add new bookmark.

Once the popup opens in the location bar minify the javascript code and put it with

```
in Location bar type

javascript: (minified javascript code)

i:e
javascript:void(imgs=Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img"),0)),void(document.body.innerHTML="");for(var i=0,l=imgs.length;l>i;i++)void(imgs[i].style.display="inline"),void document.body.appendChild(imgs[i]),void document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" "));
```

you can minify the javascript code with http://javascript-minifier.com/

BUt i found that we have to add void before every line. I dont know why